# Binary protocol thru HTTP

Tags: http, binary, protocols

I have a binary full-duplex unsecure protocol. Now I have to make it

1. secure.
2. working everywhere.

For this purpose I want to use HTTP as a transport protocol.

1. Should I create security encription on the binary level or just use HTTPS?
2. Is there a library with Send/Receive interface, that utilizes http channel?
3. How efficient is using HTTP?

Regards.

Comment: What makes you think you should use HTTP for this? How about using SSL/TLS directly instead?

Comment: AFAIK, HTTP is used in Skype to make it work behind firewalls, NATs, routers... etc by mixing own app traffic with regular web-surfing traffic. The app should work if simple web sites are available and my server IP/address is not blocked explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Bruno says in his comment: Use SSL. Plenty of libraries for all platforms.
All the security without the complexity of HTTP you have absolutely no use for anyway.
Use port 443 on the server, and no third party or intermediary will be able to distinguish your traffic from HTTPS traffic. (don't confuse "port" and "protocol".)

Also if you don't mind sharing more information about the purpose and nature of this "full duplex binary protocol", we could recommend even better existing solutions, like SRPT.